# Search multiple elements in 2D array?

Tags: numpy, search, filter, numba

I have a 1d array **match** and 2d array **data** . I can search elements one or several like this :

```
 data[data[:,0] == match[0] ]
 data[data[:,0] == match[0] & data[:,0] == match[1] ]
```

but how do you search for all of them :

```
 data[ data[:,0] == match ]
```

---

I suppose inside numba function i can use from in1d() !! :

```
    mask = np.zeros(len(ar1), dtype=bool)
    for a in ar2:
            mask |= (ar1 == a)
    return mask
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.isin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html):

```
np.isin(data[:, 0], match)
```

---

*Example*:

```
data = np.array([[1, 4],[5, 2],[2, 4]])
match = np.array([2, 4])

np.isin(data[:,0], match)
# array([False, False,  True])

data[np.isin(data[:, 0], match)]
# array([[2, 4]])
```

Comment: any chance there is other way ... numba does not support it :(

Comment: Not sure how you will use this with numba but you can also do *outer* comparison and then check if any match: `(data[:, 0][:, None] == match).any(1)`

Comment: couldnt use it inside the numba function, so now i return the full array and do it outside